# Create a column based on other column values

Tags: r

I have a data looks like following format. 
What I want to do is add new column that is main outlet location of user. Main location is the location that user purchased maximum amount. Example user2 have purchased from 3 outlets, total purchase amount of outlet2 = 14, Outlet3=34, Outlet4=26. So user2 main location is "Outlet 003"

---

- ID   Location    Amount
- 1    Outlet001      11
- 2    Outlet002      14
- 2    Outlet003      18
- 2    Outlet003      16
- 2    Outlet004      26
- 3    Outlet002      19
- 3    Outlet004      15
- 6    Outlet003      15
- 7    Outlet003      23
- 7    Outlet004      12
- 8    Outlet003      31
- 8    Outlet003      34
- 9    Outlet001      14
- 9    Outlet001      31
- 9    Outlet003      30
- 9    Outlet004      19

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of the dataset?

Comment: Do you have a desired output?

Comment: My desired output is for user1->outlet001, for user2 -> outlet003, for user3-> outlet002 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, Amount1:=sum(Amount), by=list(ID, Location)][,
             mainoutlet:=Location[which.max(Amount1)], by=ID][, Amount1:=NULL]

 df
 #   ID  Location Amount mainoutlet
 #1:  1 Outlet001     11  Outlet001
 #2:  2 Outlet002     14  Outlet003
 #3:  2 Outlet003     18  Outlet003
 #4:  2 Outlet003     16  Outlet003
 #5:  2 Outlet004     26  Outlet003
 #6:  3 Outlet002     19  Outlet002
 #7:  3 Outlet004     15  Outlet002
 #8:  6 Outlet003     15  Outlet003
 #9:  7 Outlet003     23  Outlet003
#10:  7 Outlet004     12  Outlet003
#11:  8 Outlet003     31  Outlet003
#12:  8 Outlet003     34  Outlet003
#13:  9 Outlet001     14  Outlet001
#14:  9 Outlet001     31  Outlet001
#15:  9 Outlet003     30  Outlet001
#16:  9 Outlet004     19  Outlet001
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), Location = c("Outlet001", "Outlet002", 
 "Outlet003", "Outlet003", "Outlet004", "Outlet002", "Outlet004", 
 "Outlet003", "Outlet003", "Outlet004", "Outlet003", "Outlet003", 
 "Outlet001", "Outlet001", "Outlet003", "Outlet004"), Amount = c(11L, 
 14L, 18L, 16L, 26L, 19L, 15L, 15L, 23L, 12L, 31L, 34L, 14L, 31L, 
 30L, 19L)), .Names = c("ID", "Location", "Amount"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: Seems not right. For ID 2, desired outlet should be Outlet003.

Comment: For ID 2, Outlet002 = 14, Outlet003 = 18 + 16, Outlet004 = 26.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` option to complement the other answers:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, MainOutlet = Location) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Amount)) %>%
  summarise(MainOutlet = MainOutlet[which.max(total)]) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "ID")
#   ID  Location Amount MainOutlet
#1   1 Outlet001     11  Outlet001
#2   2 Outlet002     14  Outlet003
#3   2 Outlet003     18  Outlet003
#4   2 Outlet003     16  Outlet003
#5   2 Outlet004     26  Outlet003
#6   3 Outlet002     19  Outlet002
#7   3 Outlet004     15  Outlet002
#8   6 Outlet003     15  Outlet003
#9   7 Outlet003     23  Outlet003
#10  7 Outlet004     12  Outlet003
#11  8 Outlet003     31  Outlet003
#12  8 Outlet003     34  Outlet003
#13  9 Outlet001     14  Outlet001
#14  9 Outlet001     31  Outlet001
#15  9 Outlet003     30  Outlet001
#16  9 Outlet004     19  Outlet001
```

Brief note: it's necessary to group by `ID` *and* `location` at first, in order to compute the total amount per ID and location. By using `summarise`, the last layer of the grouping variables (in this case `Location`) is peeled off, that means, after the first `summarise`, the data is only grouped by `ID`. Then, we can go on to reduce the data to only those Locations with the maximum amount sold per ID (in the second `summarise`) and that result (only 1 row per ID) is joined to the original data frame based on `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best/fastest way, but here's what I've got:

First I used just a portion of your dataset to save time.

```
ID = c(1,2,2,2,2,3,3,6,7,7)
Location = c("Outlet001","Outlet002","Outlet003","Outlet003", "Outlet004",
             "Outlet002", "Outlet004", "Outlet003", "Outlet003",
             "Outlet003")
Amount = c(11,14,18,16,26,19,15,15,23,12)  

df = data.frame("ID"=ID, "Location"=Location, "Amount"=Amount)
```

Then I used the function 'ddply' from the package 'plyr' to create a 2 new datasets: 'df2' which tells you the total amount spent per location given the user and 'df3' which gives the corresponding Main entry (the Outlet where the user spent the most total).

```
library(plyr)
df2 = ddply(df, .(ID, Location), summarize,
            Amount = sum(Amount))
df3 = ddply(df2, "ID", transform,
              Location = Location,
              Main = Location[which.max(Amount)])
```

Then I used the merge function to create the data frame I think you are looking for:

```
 df4 = merge(df,df3, by.x = c("ID", "Location"), by.y = c("ID","Location"))
```

The output looks like this:

```
    > df4
   ID  Location Amount.x Amount.y      Main
1   1 Outlet001       11       11 Outlet001
2   2 Outlet002       14       14 Outlet003
3   2 Outlet003       18       34 Outlet003
4   2 Outlet003       16       34 Outlet003
5   2 Outlet004       26       26 Outlet003
6   3 Outlet002       19       19 Outlet002
7   3 Outlet004       15       15 Outlet002
8   6 Outlet003       15       15 Outlet003
9   7 Outlet003       23       35 Outlet003
10  7 Outlet003       12       35 Outlet003
```

Note, I didn't relabel the new 'total' so after the merge, the total is represented by the column 'Amount.y'. (Amount.x is the amount listed in the original (df) set).

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well and very useful. But if data have duplicated values, it had wrong result. For user2&Outlet003 it has 2 rows and total amount should be calculated as their sum.

Comment: Hi, I think i fixed it.  There is probably a way to combine the df2 and df3 into one step, but I can't think of one off the top of my head right now. If it comes to me later, I'll post it.